# Isomorphism between $\operatorname{O}(A)$ and $\operatorname{SO}(A\times \{0\})$ for $A \subset \mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory

I was given this exercise and to be honest I can't wrap my head around this one at all. Maybe some of you can shed some light on the problem at hand. I don't want a full solution, but some hints would be nice. Here goes: 
Let $A \subset \mathbb{R}^2$, such that $A$ includes a Basis for $\mathbb{R}^2$. Prove that $\operatorname{O}(A) \cong  \operatorname{SO}(A\times \{0\})$. I think this implies, that in $\mathbb{R}^3$ a reflection through a plane or a rotation about a fixed axis can also be achieved by a single rotation about the origin(?).  However, i have no idea about how to construct the actual isomorphism. Help appreciated!

Comment: I've never heard of $O(A)$ and $SO(A\times \{0\})$ in the cases where (1) $A$ is not a vector space, and (2) $SO(A\times \{0\})$ is not isomorphic to $SO(A)$. Can you please define these things?

Comment: I share your confusion. The professor defined them as follows: Let $M \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ then $O(M) := \{m \in O_{n}(\mathbb{R}) : m\times M = M\}$ and $SO(M) := \{m \in SO_{n}(\mathbb{R}) : m\times M = M\}$. And $SO(M\times \{0\}) = \{ (x,y,0) \in \mathbb{R}^3 : (x,y) \in M \}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: The linear transformations that leave the subspace of all vectors of the form $(x,y,0)$ invariant all have matrices like
$$\left(\begin{matrix}a&b&\ast\\c&d&\ast\\0&0&\ast\end{matrix}\right)$$
Since transpose is inverse for orthogonal matrices and $SO(A\times \{0\})$ is a group, our matrices have to be of the form
$$\left(\begin{matrix}a&b&0\\c&d&0\\0&0&\ast\end{matrix}\right)$$
We can define an isomorphism $O(A)\to SO(A\times \{0\})$ by picking the $\ast$ correctly.

Comment: I think I get this now. For this to work the determinant of this transformation has to be -1 and since $ad-bc = 1$ it follows that $\ast = -1$. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @jazzinsilhouette No problem.

Comment: Ouch. I just noticed, that with $\ast = -1$ it follows that $f(AB)\neq f(A)f(B)$. Because $-1\times -1 = 1$. So $\ast$ can't be equal to -1. However, i don't see any other way to make the determinant equal to -1. Any further suggestions?

Comment: Whoops. Nevermind. I somehow overlooked the fact that this is an isomorphism of vector spaces and not a group isomorphism.

Comment: When the determinant of the 2x2 matrix is -1, make the star -1. When the determinant is 1 make the star 1. It is a group isomorphism.

Comment: Yes, thanks again. For some unfathomable reason i thought the determinant of the 3x3 matrix has to be -1 instead of 1...